# Mongodb Aggregate calculate average and add it to the document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have `websites` which contains 2 documents:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58503934034b512b419a6eab"),
    "website" : "https://www.stackoverflow.com",
    "name" : "Stack Exchange",
    "keywords" : [ 
        "helping", 
        "C#", 
        "PYTHON"
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58503934034b512b419a6eab"),
    "website" : "https://www.google.com.com",
    "name" : "Stack Exchange",
    "keywords" : [ 
        "search", 
        "engine", 
    ]
}
```

I also have another `seo_tracking` which contains:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("587373d6f6325811c8a0b3ad"),
    "position" : "2",
    "real_url" : "https://www.stackoverflow.com",
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-01-09T11:28:22.104Z"),
    "keyword" : "helping"
},
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("587373d6f6325811c8a0b3ad"),
   "position" : "4",
   "real_url" : "https://www.stackoverflow.com",
   "created_at" : ISODate("2017-01-09T11:28:22.104Z"),
   "keyword" : "C#"
}
```

etc.. This contains around 100+ documents

What I want to do is is aggregate the `seo_tracking` with `website` on the specific URL (`www.stackexchange` (in `websites`) would match `www.stackoverflow.com` in (`seo_tracking`)) which I can do fine. However, I would like to return for each of the `websites` the following:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("587373d6f6325811c8a0b3ad"),
    "website":"https://www.stackoverflow.com", 
    "avg_position" : "2"
}
```

Then for Google etc.. Even if the `avg_position` is 0 .. I have tried the following:

```
db.seo_tracking.aggregate([

    {
        $lookup:
        {
            from: "websites", 
            localField: "real_url", 
            foreignField: "website", 
            as: "post_websites"
         },
     },
     {
        "$group": {
           _id:null, 
          avg_position:{$avg:"$position"}
          }
      } 
])
```

However, this just produces:

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "avg_position" : 2.0
}
```

What I need to do is have `website` and ideally also need the `ID`

Any ideas to where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: `$avg` works on numerical values, and some of your `position` values are strings.

Comment: @chridam If I changed the "n/a"  to `0` could this work?

Comment: Long as the fields resolve to a number then you will get the correct average.

Comment: @chridam The issue isn't the `avg_position` I've already figured this out. What I want to do is have the `website_url`, `website_name` returned with the average position -- If this makes sense?

Comment: @chridam It currently returns `{
    "_id" : null,
    "avg_position" : 2.0
}` 

Whereas I want it to return:
`
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("587373d6f6325811c8a0b3ad"),
    "website":"https://www.stackoverflow.com", 
    "avg_position" : "2"
}`

Comment: @Phorce Add them to keep in `$group` stage. Something like `website:{$first:"$website"}` and you can use `$out` to update the collection.

Comment: @SagarReddy This displays the URL just fine. The issue is that there are 3 entries for `https://www.stackoverflow.com` whereas I just need it to display one for `https://www.stackoverflow.com` and the average for all of the keyword entries in `seo_tracking` if that makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this. You'll need to [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to access the fields from joined collection and change your grouping key to use the `_id` from joined collection to get average for each website:

```
db.seo_tracking.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "website",
        localField: "real_url",
        foreignField: "website",
        as: "post_websites"
    },
}, {
    $unwind: "$post_websites"
}, {
    "$group": {
        _id: "$post_websites._id",
        avg_position: {
            $avg: "$position"
        },
        website: {
            $first: "$real_url"
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The issue is that I'm getting: `Found 0 record(s)` taking off the `$unwind` gives me 1 value back for `https://www.stackoverflow.com` and works out the average for `https://www.google.com .. Where there should be 2 collections returned.. The average for `https://www.stackoverflow.com` and the collection for `https://www.google.com`

Comment: No such luck. Still returning 0 results with `$unwind`

Comment: did you change the grouping key to `post_websites._id` ? I'll try adding some samples and test on my side.

Comment: IT WORKS! It's been one of them days, very very sorry!! Thanks so much for the help :D